# Why do i get a "Value" error when updating cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a big formula in a cell, that works completely well until any cell of the sheet is updated by clicking or adding any text to it. If I update any cell again, it goes back to normal. Does anyone know how to fix this?

That is my function (in PT_BR):

```
=SE(B3>64;CONCATENAR(SE(B3>64;int(B3/64);"-");" pack(s)";SE(B3=C3*64;"";CONCATENAR(" e ";SE(B3=C3*64;"";B3-((int(B3/64)*64)))))))
```

**Expected table using the function:**

| Total | Formatted value |
| --- | --- |
| 6697 | 104 pack(s) e 41 |
| 6203 | 96 pack(s) e 59 |
| 4877 | 76 pack(s) e 13 |
| 3733 | 58 pack(s) e 21 |
| 2930 | 45 pack(s) e 50 |
| 2179 | 34 pack(s) e 3 |

**Output table:**

| Total | Formatted value |
| --- | --- |
| 6697 | #VALUE! |
| 6203 | #VALUE! |
| 4877 | #VALUE! |
| 3733 | #VALUE! |
| 2930 | #VALUE! |
| 2179 | #VALUE! |

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YsPE0CNscZ8Le40rwt9zo4pdTnWTNpDGWTegFcEgA_I/edit?usp=sharing here it is

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in your C3:C range and use this in C3:

```
=INDEX(IF(A3:A="";;IF(B3:B>64; INT(B3:B/64)&" pack(s) e "&
 IF(B3:B=(INT(B3:B/64))*64; 0; B3:B-((INT(B3:B/64)*64))); "-")))
```

[image]